# Is it possible to override "main" entrypoint in third party npm dependency?

Tags: knockout.js, npm

For some reason unknown to me Knockout declares its debug build as "main" in package.json: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/v3.4.2/package.json#L8

Is it possible to override this with the production build instead?

Comment: Actually there is no much sense to use minified code in Node.js because minifying the code usually has no impact to the performance but is done to conserve the bandwidth. So using the debug version of KO on the server is normal in this case.

Comment: @AndrejsKuzmins No, the Knockout debug build is actually different. Have a look here: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L96 https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/3949c3e067636f90fcf3abfc1dd9e9b0aae9b308/src/subscribables/dependentObservable.js#L83

Comment: afaik the debug build lacks optimizations made for browser environments only. Yes, it exposes some properties for debugging purposes but I'm pretty sure that all core features accessible in Node.js will work with no loss of efficiency.